# when did I give the application a root permissions?

Tags: permissions, security, root, application

I've installed azure storage explorer with "sudo snap install".
I don't remember giving it root permissions during the installation.
Now it's creating directories owned by root for downloaded files.

Does it mean that if I install an application from the internet,
it can do whatever it wants on my machine?

Comment: *Now it's creating directories owned by root for downloaded files.* - how do you know?

Comment: If you install an application using `sudo` then you are giving the app the permissions to do what it was designed to do. If the app is designed maliciously, then you have a problem. If you install only from trusted sources then you're likely OK.

Comment: 1. When you start it, it creates a folder in /tmp: drwx------ 3 root     root     4096 lut  2 15:36 snap.storage-explorer.
2. I gave the installer the sudo permissions, to install files in root-owned folders. I didn't give the permissions to the application, did I?

Comment: It's Snap.  Maybe the container system needs to be running as root and needs some files of it's own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "snap"'s permissions depends on how it is set up.
As per design each Snap runs in its own sandbox. However, totally isolated packages in sandboxes don't work for a lot of use cases. Therefore there is the concept of "interfaces" which allows access to "things" outside of the sandbox. [This ubuntu blog](https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-guide-to-snap-permissions-and-interfaces) explains the concept pretty nicely.

Additionally different [levels of confinement](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) exist within snaps and you can check out how your installed app is configured.

The biggest problem with your questions is, that snaps don't make the user aware of very loosely set permissions and to answer your question: yes a badly designed or malicious snap could do whatever it wants to your system.